# Tree - elements influence on another elements. Searching for specific elements

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am supposed to create an algorithm, but I don't know where to start.

I have got a tree, for example:

```
(1)                     1
                     /  |  \
                    2   3   4
                  / | \     | \
                 5  6  7    8  9
                            |
                            10
```

One of the elements (persons) is infected. How much drugs (from 0 to 1) do we need to assign in order to prevent infecting k people. If the ratio of infected children will be greater than the amount of drugs, then also the parent and all the other children will be infected. Not only the nodes on the lowest level can be infected at the start, but when the infected at the start has got children then those children won't be infected. The algorithm should be okay for 500000 elements.

Some examples for the (1) tree:

**INPUT:** 3   (number of people to prevent from infecting)

```
                        1
                     /  |  \
                    2   3   4
                  / | \     | \
                 5  6  7    8  9
                            |
                            10     <-- The easiest target
 Wee see that if 10 will be infected, the only child from 8, then the drugs
 should be on level 0.6666666 (2/3) to prevent getting the virus to more than 3  
 people (because 10 and 8 are infected, but to infect 4 more than (2/3) his
 children should be infected and if 4 would be infected then 9 also).
```

**OUTPUT:** 0.6666666

**INPUT:** 4   (number of people to prevent from infecting)

```
                        1
                     /  |  \
                    2   3   4
                  / | \     | \
                 5  6  7    8  9
                            |
                            10     <-- The easiest target
 If the drug level will be on 0.4444444 (4/9) and the target will be 10 then the 
 virus will infect (10->8->4->9).
```

**OUTPUT:** 0.4444444

Comment: This looks like computer science homework and should probably be asked on the [computer science stack](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you, I will try my luck there.